# Implementing new TFGAN module

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on implementing the new TFGAN module in tensorflow [TFGAN Module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan/README.md)

Has anyone been able to actually get it working?  I'm running into issues passing tf.random.noise into a simplistic generator:

```
tfgan = tf.contrib.gan
noise = tf.random_normal([BATCH_SIZE, 28,28])

def my_generator(z, out_dim=28*28, n_units=128, reuse=False, alpha=0.01):    
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):
        # Hidden layer
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(z, n_units, activation=None)

        # Leaky ReLU
        h1 = tf.maximum(h1, alpha*h1)

        # Logits and tanh output
        logits = tf.layers.dense(h1, out_dim, activation=None)
        out = tf.nn.tanh(logits)

    return out, logits
```

Then the tfgan call:

```
# Build the generator and discriminator.
gan_model = tfgan.gan_model(
    generator_fn=my_generator,  
    discriminator_fn=my_discriminator,  
    real_data=images,
    generator_inputs=noise)
```

`Error: "tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'"`, pointing to my generator_inputs line.

(As a side note, I've done almost all of my NN work at the keras level abstraction, so I know this is an easy question)

---

EDIT PER COMMENTS FROM kvorobiev (Thank you very much)

Code excluding data generator (basically the same as the post on github)

```
tfgan = tf.contrib.gan
noise = tf.random_normal([28,28])


def unconditional_generator(z, out_dim=28*28, n_units=128, reuse=False,  alpha=0.01):    
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=reuse):
        # Hidden layer
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(z, n_units, activation=None)
        # Leaky ReLU
        h1 = tf.maximum(h1, alpha*h1)

        # Logits and tanh output
        logits = tf.layers.dense(h1, out_dim, activation=None)
        out = tf.nn.tanh(logits)

        return out, logits

def unconditional_discriminator(x, n_units=128, reuse=False, alpha=0.01):
     with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):
        # Hidden layer
        h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, n_units, activation=None)

        # Leaky ReLU
        h1 = tf.maximum(h1, alpha*h1)

        logits = tf.layers.dense(h1, 1, activation=None)
        out = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)

        return out, logits

# Build the generator and discriminator.
gan_model = tfgan.gan_model(
    generator_fn= unconditional_generator,  # you define
    discriminator_fn = unconditional_discriminator,  # you define
    real_data=img_generator,
    generator_inputs=noise)

# Build the GAN loss.
gan_loss = tfgan.gan_loss(
    gan_model,
    generator_loss_fn=tfgan_losses.wasserstein_generator_loss,
    discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan_losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss)

# Create the train ops, which calculate gradients and apply updates to weights.
train_ops = tfgan.gan_train_ops(
    gan_model,
    gan_loss,
    generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(gen_lr, 0.5),
    discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(dis_lr, 0.5))

# Run the train ops in the alternating training scheme.
tfgan.gan_train(
    train_ops,
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=100)],
    logdir=FLAGS.train_log_dir)
```

Traceback:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-2c570c5257d0> in <module>()
     37     discriminator_fn = unconditional_discriminator,  # you define
     38     real_data=img_generator,
---> 39     generator_inputs=noise)
     40 
     41 # Build the GAN loss.

~/tf_1.4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/train.py in gan_model(generator_fn, discriminator_fn, real_data, generator_inputs, generator_scope, discriminator_scope, check_shapes)
    105   with variable_scope.variable_scope(discriminator_scope) as dis_scope:
    106     discriminator_gen_outputs = discriminator_fn(generated_data,
--> 107                                                  generator_inputs)
    108   with variable_scope.variable_scope(dis_scope, reuse=True):
    109     real_data = ops.convert_to_tensor(real_data)

<ipython-input-3-2c570c5257d0> in unconditional_discriminator(x, n_units, reuse, alpha)
     19      with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=reuse):
     20         # Hidden layer
---> 21         h1 = tf.layers.dense(x, n_units, activation=None)
     22 
     23         # Leaky ReLU

~/tf_1.4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py in dense(inputs, units, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, trainable, name, reuse)
    245                 trainable=trainable,
    246                 name=name,
--> 247                 dtype=inputs.dtype.base_dtype,
    248                 _scope=name,
    249                 _reuse=reuse)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Actually, error occurred on `tfgan.gan_model` call. Post full error traceback and code for all arguments of `tfgan.gan_model`.

Comment: Posted - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

2 points:

1) I believe your error is coming from the second argument of your discriminator. If you use the library call, TFGAN expects the second argument to be whatever conditioning you want (could be the input noise to the unconditional case, the class in the conditional case, structured noise in InfoGAN, etc). Your definition is using `noise` as `n_units`, which is likely causing the type mismatch. To fix this, just make your second discriminator argument unused instead of `n_dims`.

2) I am in the review process of open sourcing a number of useful / illustrative examples (unconditional/conditional/InfoGAN on MNIST, distributed training on CIFAR, an adversarial loss on image compression, image-to-image translation, etc). They'll appear here very soon: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research.

Comment: Thank you Joel.  You seem to be correct.  I am now running into other issues that I believe related to passing in my custom data (not MNIST).  Rather than go back and forth I"ll wait to see your examples. Thanks again.

Comment: They're up. Please let me know if you have any questions about them.